# Why is the Chrome-Lighthouse user agent hitting my server every day?

Tags: googlebot, apache2, google-chrome, logging, lighthouse

Every day, I find lines like this one in my `access.log` file:

> 74.125.210.42 - - [08/Mar/2023:08:11:13 +0100] "GET /fr/ HTTP/2.0" 200 24160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4590.2 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse"

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Related on Stack Overflow: [What is the name of the Google PageSpeed User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446950/2234742)